# Не прозрачный фон у кнопки когда она поверх видео плеера QVideoWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qpushbutton, qmediaplayer, qvideowidget

Я хочу сделать видео плеер как в ютубе и т.д., с появляющимися кнопками поверх плеера при движении курсора. 
Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что как бы я не пытался заставить фон кнопки быть прозрачным, фон оставался белым или иногда чёрным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот методы, которые я пытался:

```
play_button.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
play_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")
play_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); border: none;")
```

---

А также пытался ставить **`.png`** иконку.

---

Вот сам код базы плеера:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl


class VideoPlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(self)

        videowidget = QVideoWidget(self)
        videowidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 720)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videowidget)

        icon_path = 'C:/Users/maxim/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/app/icons_player/pause.png'
        icon = QIcon(QPixmap(icon_path))

        #кнопка
        play_button = QPushButton(self)
        play_button.setGeometry(640 - 25, 360 - 25, 50, 50)  # Позиция и размер кнопки
        play_button.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        #play_button.setIcon(icon)
        play_button.clicked.connect(self.play_video)
        self.play_video()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1280, 720)

    def play_video(self):
        # Загружаем видеофайл
        media_content = QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile('C:/fate.mp4'))
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(media_content)

        # Воспроизводим видео
        self.mediaPlayer.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Попробуйте кнопку вывести в .png, возможно получится

Comment: Честно говоря не в курсе, получится ли так сделать, но что если взять область пикселей в центре (под кнопкой), размыть их и отрисовать градиент на самой кнопке. Должно выглядеть более-менее эстетично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не получится установить прозрачный фон у кнопки когда она поверх `QVideoWidget`.
`QVideoWidget` по умолчанию не поддерживает альфа-каналы. 
Вы можете только придать кнопке какой-то фон, близкий к фону отображаемого видео.

Ниже пример, который демонстрирует что возможно
сделать при использовании `QVideoWidget`.

---

Рассмотрите возможность использования `QGraphicsVideoItem`
вместо `QVideoWidget` и встраивание его в `QGraphicsView`,
тогда другие элементы можно сделать дочерними по отношению к `QGraphicsVideoItem`, чтобы он был сверху.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class VideoWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player Widget Example - pythonprogramminglanguage.com")

        self.mediaPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(
            None, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        videoWidget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()
        videoWidget.setObjectName('videoWidget')

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()          
        container.setObjectName('container')
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(videoWidget)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            container, objectName='pushButton')
        self.pushButton.setIcon(
            self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.play_video)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton.hide()

        self.playButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setIcon(
            self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.errorLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.errorLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                      QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        openAction = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open movie')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        exitAction = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        wid.setObjectName('wid')
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)

        controlLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(container)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.errorLabel)
        wid.setLayout(layout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)

    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Open Movie",
            "",
            "MP4 Video (*.mp4);;OGG Video (*.ogg);;AVI Video (*.avi)"
        )

        if fileName:
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
            
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.pushButton.show()
            
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())
        
    def play_video(self):
        # Воспроизводим видео
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
            self.pushButton.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()        
            self.pushButton.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
      
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        x = self.width() // 2 - 10
        y = self.height() - 110
        self.pushButton.move(x, y)
        
 
StyleSheet = '''
#wid {
    background: #A0522D;
}
#container, #videoWidget {
    background: #F4A460;
}

#pushButton {
    background: rgba( 55, 55, 255, 0); 
    max-width: 16px;
    max-height: 16px;
}
#pushButton:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: red;
}
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.resize(540, 480)
    player.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(190, 220))
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]